# What is wrong with this sed command?

Tags: bash, sed

I am facing a strange problem. An answer to what I want to do already exists [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219938/delete-trailing-commas-in-line). I am trying to remove trailing commas from each line of a file containing thousands of lines. Like this -

[image]

This is my command -

```
sed -i 's/,*$//g' file_name.csv
```

However, the output I get is exactly the same as the image above and the trailing commas are not removed.

I think SED is not matching the pattern and thus failing to replace the commas. To check if there are any hidden characters in the file, I used VIM's **:set list** option -

[image]

There are only **$** at the end of each line which is just what is expected.

I can't understand why the command is failing.

Comment: try `sed  's/,\+$//g'`

Comment: also don't post pictures of plain text. just copy and paste the text verbatim

Comment: `sed 's/,*.$//g'` may do it

Comment: I just tried the above commands. Didn't work.

Comment: The example have 7 unwanted , in every line you could simply do `sed 's/,,,,,,,//g'` but this will not bind to the end of line (so this is not failproof). The above commands should work so there is something strange with this file, also this why @sashang mentioned to give us example as text so we able to test commands with the actual data you have to modify.

Comment: vi may not show '^M' characters beause open the file in dos mode, try `cat -ve`

Comment: `sed 's/,*$//'` should suffice, no need for `/g` since `$` will be matched just once.

Comment: to see ^M characters in vi `:e ++ff=unix`, to change line endings `:e ++ff=dos` and `set ff=unix`

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you two options: 
First One is my favorite.

```
     dos2unix file 
#####will work for Huge File also
```

then try to run the command.

Other way to do this:

```
cat file | tr -d '\r' > file
###may not work for huge file
```

then run the command.

```
tr -d '\r' < file > file.tmp ; mv file.tmp file 
    ##will work for Huge File also
```

Thanks to  @Nahuel for suggesting last command.

Comment: the second command is wrong, cat is useless and file may be truncated before to be read

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul If its very huge file. then Yes :)

Comment: a temporary file can be used: `tr -d '\r' < file > file.tmp ; mv file.tmp file`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Thanks. Updated.